# What is the best way to search if a value is unique in a column in pandas paquet format?

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, parquet

I have a table I put into a pandas object using

```
pd.read_parquet(filename)
```

I have 3 columns of interest in the data set, 2 are data, one is an ID. I have to search through the whole set for values, but discard duplicate Id's.

What is the fastest way to put these id's in a data structure, or maybe clean the data for duplicates first? I was thinking of a dictionary, but there might be a way to do this already using pandas faster, or use some sort of cashe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`pd.read_parquet(filename).drop_duplicates(['ID'])`

Comment: You can pass `ignore_index=True` as a parameter to drop dups, and your result df will have a nice and new RangeIndex